# How to convert binary content from a request that contains a docx to an actual docx file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, docx

I wanted to know if there is a strategy to convert binary content to docx. More precisely, I have the docx stored as a blob in a database. I want to use python to get it and store it as a docx somewhere. I have a GET request that I can use to get a hold of the file, but not sure how to convert it to docx.

Specifics:

```
r = requests.get(url)
r.content = b'SomeStuffThatLooksLikeXMLinfo'
```

I could save that as a .bin but no idea how to convert it to a docx file.

I tried saving it as a .bin file but that is useless. I don't know if there is a package that does this or what I can use. Basically using python I want to go from binary to docx.

Comment: additional info: mime type is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`

Answer (score 0):

Think your step of using "requests.get()" is fine. To convert it to docx you probably need the python-docx library. Not sure if you're already using it, otherwise choose pip install in this case.

Your code probably expects a binary stream. So your code might look like this:

```
r = requests.get(url)
binaryStream = io.BytesIO(r.content)
yourDocument = Document()
yourDocument.open(binaryStream, content_type="your mime type")
yourDocument.save("your/prefered/path")
```

Comment: there is no `open` and no `content-type`. Why I just feed it the bytes it says it is not a zip file

Comment: you need to make sure you have all your imports in it and all libraries are installed (e.g. `pip install python-docx`). you need `from docx import Document` inside the code aswell.

Comment: Yes, did those things, the Document class has no `content_type` and no `open` method. See https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#document-constructor for reference

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given a testable URL and it is not abundantly clear to me what the exact issue is.

As you appear to have the contents of a valid MS-Word document, you shouldn't need any extra packages for manipulating such documents, you should just need to write what you have to a `docx` file.

```
import pathlib

r = requests.get(...)

pathlib.Path('document.docx').write_bytes(r.content)
```

---

Or you should be able to use plain old:

```
with open('document.docx', 'wb') as fd:
    fd.write(r.content)
```